# Encode a shapefile in gml 3.2

Tags: java, geotools, gml

I am not so seasoned about gis and geotools, I am trying to encode a feature collection obtained by a shapefile in gml 3.2. Here is my code:

```
@Test
public void transformAccumuliDiFranaShapeToGml32() throws IOException {
  URL zipfile = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("my.shape.zipped");

  File unzippedFile = new File(tmpFolder, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
unzippedFile.mkdirs();
  File zippedFile = new File(zipfile.getPath());
getUncompressed(zippedFile, unzippedFile);
  File shapefile = getFileBySuffix(unzippedFile, ".shp");

  FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shapefile);
  SimpleFeatureCollection features = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures();

  Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration();
org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder(configuration);
  FileOutputStream fos = null;
  try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(tmpFolder, UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".32.gml"));
    encoder.encode(features, org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.FeatureCollection, fos);
  } finally {
    if (fos != null)
    fos.close();
  }
}
```

All I can get is an empty gml file. This is the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"/>
```

Maybe it depends by the `QName` value I pass to `encoder.encode(..);`. You can find the shapefile I used [here](https://www.dati.lombardia.it/download/m72w-vbad/application/zip). What am I missing? I am using org.geotools version 17.2.